# Clicking video button that is inside scrollable div, moves it to the right

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I created a fiddle to demonstrate the issue. [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/2ypdaqbx/4/)

You can realize that the div has a 200% width and a translate attribute

```
  <div class="container">
    <video controls="controls">
      <source 
        src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" 
        type="video/mp4"
      >
    </video>
  </div>

  .container{
        width: 200%;
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
   }
```

You can go to the fiddle and click the three-dot item in the right-bottom corner (**Google Chrome 67+**). You will show that the event, moves the container to the right.

If I switch *transform: translate(0px, 0px);* to *left:0; top:0;* it will work.

My question is: Why this new player has that strange behavior and how to manage it without change the containers transform.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the width of the container to 100% and it is not correct to set width as 200%

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
 }

 .container video{
    width: 100%;
    height: 360px;
  }
```

Comment: I need that width in my specific application.